# How do I plot TRUE values over time in R?

Tags: r, plot, linegraph

For example I have a data frame like this:

```
Year|Value
2013|TRUE
2013|TRUE
2013|TRUE
2013|TRUE
2013|FALSE
2013|FALSE
2013|TRUE
2013|FALSE
2014|TRUE
2014|FALSE
2014|FALSE
2014|TRUE
2015|TRUE
2015|TRUE
2015|FALSE
2015|FALSE
2015|TRUE
2015|TRUE
```

I want to plot a line graph of total amounts of truth per year.

I have tried

```
data <- data.frame('t'=year, 'a'=Value)
plot(data)
```

...but it gives year at the x-axis and on y-axis either 0 or 1 (which is true or false. rather than the number of `TRUE`s per year.

Comment: R is 'dumb' and will only plot what you give it. You're plotting `1` (TRUE) and `0` (FALSE) repeatedly by year. You need to `?aggregate` your data first to count the values - `plot(Value ~ Year, data=aggregate(Value ~ Year, data=dat, sum), type="l")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to plot a line graph of total amounts of truth per year.

The trick is in transforming your data to show what you'd like your plot to show: the truth *count* for each year, not each observed year-boolean.

Here's a `dplyr` approach to reducing the data. It filters for `TRUE` values and then counts how many rows of `TRUE` values appear for each year.

### reduce

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tab = structure(list(Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), Value = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)), .Names = c("Year", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
tab_sum = tab %>% group_by(Year) %>%
  filter(Value) %>%
  summarise(trues = n()) 
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#    Year trues
#   (int) (int)
# 1  2013     5
# 2  2014     2
# 3  2015     4
```

### plot

Now each row in the data gives an `x` and `y` pair for the plot:

```
ggplot(tab_sum, aes(Year, trues)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: You need to explain/document your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a histogram of the True values, is that right? If so, here's the easiest way to do that:

### Recreating your dataset:

```
year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
     2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
     2015, 2015, 2015, 2015,2015, 2015) 

value = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
      TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
      TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) 

data <- data.frame('year'=year, 'value'=value)

data$year_factor<-as.factor(as.character(data$year))

data$year_date<-as.Date(as.character(data$year), "%Y")
```

Basically you're asking for a count of the true values per year
So we'll segment our dataset, so it only contains True values:

```
shortdata <-data[data$value,]
```

#### The ugly version:

```
hist(shortdata$year_date, breaks = 3, freq = T)
```

[image]

#### The rough, but slightly prettier version:

```
qplot(shortdata$year)
```

[image]

But, ok, you want a line-graph version. Here's how you do that.

### Line graph version:

```
require(plyr)

freqdf = ddply(shortdata, .(year_factor), summarize, 
               freq = length(year_factor))

freqdf$year_factor <-as.numeric(as.character(freqdf$year_factor))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=freqdf, aes(x=year_factor, y=freq))+geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 6))+
  ggtitle("True Values Over Three Years")
```

[image]

Hope this helps! Good luck with your graphing!